# USB only KVM with Full DDM support?

Tags: usb, kvm

Requirements:

- USB Full-DDM (so each computer always detects a keyboard and mouse)
- 2 USB type A ports
- no bigger than 5"x4"x1"-ish
- Below $300

Nice-to-Haves:

- Remote selector switch (not wireless/ir)
- USB 3.0

I currently use a Logitech k740 and Logitech M500s mouse (no special macro keys or drivers) and a generic USB switch. I am trying to find a USB only switch that supports Dynamic Device Mapping to reduce switching times between two computers. Unfortunately, every listing I have found for an USB switch does not support this.

I do not have a need to switch other USB devices, just keyboard and mouse.

I know there are full size KVMs that support this, but I don't have the space for them. I am limited to about 5"x4"x2" space (plus or minus an inch or two). If there is a KVM switch that is that small, I am open to recommendations.

.

For those who are wondering, the reason I don't use a regular full featured KVM is because I require the ability to switch each of my 3 monitors individually, while also switching my keyboard/mouse independently of the video. As far as I am aware, there is no KVM that can do that.

Comment: Did you found any ?

Comment: Nope. Haven't found anything